# MSP430 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, msp430

I'm working on a project which requires to generate pulses with specific pulse width, frequency, intensity..  so i need to choose a microcontroller to use..
The pulses that i want needs to be biphasic, due to that, i want to use msp430 microcontroller, but i don't really know what i need to program it, it's my first to use it.. so  what software and  hardware i need to have to be able to program it?
MSP430F169 is the one that i chose

Comment: This question is too broad. We can't teach you to program microcontrollers. There are nice tutorials and even online courses for that you can find for free.

Comment: I'm not asking to teach me.. I'm considering many ways to do my project.. and this is one of them.. and due to where i live, i need to bring some parts from other countries, so i need to evaluate what i need to program it.. and sure I'll be looking for for online courses.. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like, due to your questions on basic hardware and software setup, that you should start with the [MSP-EXP430G2 Launchpad](http://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2).  It's US$10 and has all the hardware you need to familiarize yourself with MSP430.

For software programming, you can use TI's [Code Composer Studio](http://www.ti.com/tool/ccstudio) for an Eclipse-based IDE, or [Energia](http://energia.nu/) for an Arduino interface (note that the latter only supports a few microcontrollers, but the included MSP430G2553 is supported).
[image: MSP430G2553]
After getting acquainted with this board and software you can start messing with more advanced microcontrollers and features.  In fact, I still use my MSP-EXP430G2 to program off-board MSP430 chips using something like this [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/EASY-MSP430-LaunchPad-ISP-with-only-4-wires/).

Comment: @user142362 No problem!  Also check out free online courses on [edX](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-world-utaustinx-ut-6-10x) and [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-embedded-systems) that deal with embedded systems and TI microcontrollers specifically.

Comment: Again thank you! I'll check it out... i know now where to start

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with calcium3000, and will never advise anybody **today** to buy unsupported and not-updatable G2 LP, with extremely slow stone-age on board (SBW) FET that is limited to debug/flash only G2 familly. I also disagree on using stone-age F1xx family **today**, for starting new (even LED blink) projects.

For example, **today**, MSP-EXP430FR2433 is 4.30$ (with shipping included in price) with open hardware / software eZ-FET Lite on board that support all TI SBW devices and it is updatable.

https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/msp430blog/archive/2017/11/08/introductory-price-of-4-30-for-msp430fr2433-mcu-launchpad-kit

For some basic intro (PWM included), check linked document with open source examples...
http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/swab003/swab003.pdf

Comment: US$4.30 until December 2017?!  Nice find - couldn't find that in the Launchpad section of TI's site.  I'm looking into the FR series for my new projects, too, but I'm always pleased with having a DIP socket for eval boards.  They may be closer to 'stone-age' but they're simple, fast enough for most purposes, and provide a good base to further learning.